# How do I find the number of times a file was revised in subversion?

Tags: svn

Given a file, how do I find out number of times the file was revised? The head revision number may be in hundreds but I would have revised a file just 4 times. Thus given that file, I want 4 as the answer. Sounds pretty trivial but I was unable to find any command to achieve this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

Use `svn log -q filename | grep '^r' | wc -l`

Comment: -1 count is wrong, should have tested this first ... svn log is more verbose than you think

Answer (score 4):

```
svn log FOO.C -q | grep -c r
```

`svn log -q` prints summary information for the given file or directory in the log, and `grep -c r` counts the number of lines containing the letter "r" (basically we just want to ignore the spacer lines "--------")

Comment: Agreed, doing the count in grep is a nice touch. However, using the pattern '^r' is probably a better idea, so it only matches lines that start with r, which is faster since it doesn't have to search the entire ---- line to know it doesn't match. Also, I generally put the option flags before the main argument (in this case, the filename) but that's a matter of style.

Comment: svn log -q [filename] | grep -c '^r'

Answer (score 2):

[The Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) explains:

> You can also examine the log history of a single file or directory. For example:
>
> $ svn log foo.c
>
> $ svn log
>   http://foo.com/svn/trunk/code/foo.c
>
> *These will display log messages only for those revisions in which the
>   working file (or URL) changed.*

Full description of the log command is [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't 'svn log' provide you with the information you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain Subversion contains a View History mechanism within the Repo Browser.

Are you using Tortoise with Subversion?

Comment: Subversion itself doesn't have a repo browser — you must be thinking of features in TortoiseSVN (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org).

Answer (score 0):

This oughta do it:

svn log -q  | grep -v "\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-" | wc -l